# How to cut a variable to sub variable

Tags: shell, awk, cut

I have a variable which store consist of

> TITLE:AUTHOR:PRICE:QUANTITY:SOLDQUANTITY

in this case its

> wrinkle in time:myauthor:50.00:**20**:50

I store it in

```
Result=`awk -F : -v "Title=$1" -v "Author=$2" 'tolower($1) == tolower(Title) && tolower($2) == tolower(Author)' BookDB.txt`
```

however I would like to separate it into 4 variables like

```
TITLE= "wrinkle in time"
AUTHOR= "myauthor"
PRICE= "50.00"
Quantity= "20"
UNIT= "50"
```

then I would like to do a calculation for unit sold

> enter unit sold: 3
>
> wrinkle in time, myauthor, 50.00, 20, 50
>
> after update
>
> wrinkle in time, myauthor, 50.00, 17, 53

thanks in advance your help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate `$result` into the different variables you describe by using `read`:

```
IFS=: read TITLE AUTHOR PRICE QUANTITY UNIT <<< "$result"
```

Example:

```
$ result="wrinkle in time:myauthor:50.00:20:50"
$ IFS=: read TITLE AUTHOR PRICE QUANTITY UNIT <<< "$result"
$ echo "$TITLE - by - $AUTHOR"
wrinkle in time - by - myauthor
```

You can also use `read` to prompt a user for input:

```
read -p "Enter units sold: " SOLDUNITS
```

This will store the value entered in the variable `$SOLDUNITS`. You can then use this to alter `$QUANTITY` and `$UNIT` as desired. To do (integer) arithmetic in `bash`, you can use the `$((expression))` construct:

```
QUANTITY=$((QUANTITY-SOLDUNITS))
```

Or:

```
((QUANTITY-=SOLDUNITS))
```